# Variable has already been defined in my method, or has it?

Tags: java, variables, boolean

Consider the following method

```
public static boolean choosePlayer()
{
   String whatPlayer = input("Are you Player 1 or Player 2?");
   boolean player1;
   if (whatPlayer.equalsIgnoreCase("Player 1"))
   {
       boolean player1 = true;
   }    
   else
   {
       boolean player1 = false;
   }  
   return player1;
}
```

I simply want this method to find out if the user is indeed player 1 and give me back `player1` as `true` and `false` if they are not player 1. I get the compiler error

> variable player1 is already defined in method choosePlayer()

If I remove the line of code `boolean player1`, then it complains that it can't find the variable `player1`.

I know I'm missing something simple but my brain is in mush-mode and it would be awesome if someone could point out my blunder. Thanks

Comment: Remove `boolean` in `boolean player1 = true;`, same for `false`.

Comment: Ha! It certainly has been a long day for me.. Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second declaration of `player1` applies only inside the if statements, so you should keep only the first declaration.

```
public static boolean choosePlayer()
{
   String whatPlayer = input("Are you Player 1 or Player 2?");
   boolean player1;
   if (whatPlayer.equalsIgnoreCase("Player 1"))
   {
       player1 = true;
   }    
   else
   {
       player1 = false;
   }  
   return player1;
}
```

Of course you can reduce this code to :

```
public static boolean choosePlayer()
{
   String whatPlayer = input("Are you Player 1 or Player 2?");
   return whatPlayer.equalsIgnoreCase("Player 1");
}
```

or even

```
public static boolean choosePlayer()
{
   return input("Are you Player 1 or Player 2?").equalsIgnoreCase("Player 1");
}
```

So you don't need that variable at all.